# Why is there no ISO or ECMA standardization for C# later than 2.0?

Tags: c#, iso, ecma

I have started learning C# and was looking for a standard specification, but found that C# versions greater than 2.0 were not standardized by ISO or ECMA (or so I gathered from Wikipedia). Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because writing, reviewing, validating, publishing, processing feedback, revising, re-publishing etc complex specification documents takes significant time and effort, which is a finite resource - and the demand for an ISO / ECMA version of the specification hasn't been sufficient to prompt Microsoft into investing that time.

The non-Microsoft compiler authors (Mono etc) seem to be doing just fine without it.

Anecdotally, it also avoids the problem where 2 specifications *say different conflicting things* (which can happen, and has happened).

Comment: @Jude precisely; that is the c# 2 version from 2006. The question is: why nothing since?

Answer (score 0):

[ECMA-334:2022](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/) has published June 2022，which is based on C# 6.0

Microsoft [has](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-open-source-c-standardization-standards/) opensourced C# standardization on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard) and is still working on C# 7.0 Standard.